# Графика в Visual Studio С++

Tags: c++, графика

Решил научиться работать с графикой в с++, так , чтобы можно в будущем делать простые и сложные игрушки. Посоветуйте книги , сборники по графике  в  visual studio С++

P.s можно ли основываясь на книгах о графике в **C++ Builder** работать в **Visual Studio**?

Comment: Об играх - вот такая классика: http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0422-6.html и http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0627-X.html

Comment: Можно ли основываясь на книгах о графике в C++ Builder работать в Visual Studio?

Comment: @MickeyU если примеры заточены конкретно под builder и библиотеку vcl (например, используется объект canvas из vcl), то не получится.

Comment: Для начала вам стоит разобраться с терминологией, Visual Studio и C++ Builder - это IDE, вместо них стоит ориентироваться на некоторые фундаментальные вещи и конкретные графические API (DirectX, OpenGl, Vulcan).

Comment: Просто выберите графическую библиотеку, и начните ее осваивать. (Советую SDL2. Она довольно проста в использовании, и плюс, когда перерастете простенькую встроенную графику, поверх нее можно поставить OpenGL, который уже серьезнее.) Простую 2Д графику освоить не слишком сложно, так что не советую пока заморачиваться с книгами. (Есть риск потратить кучу времени на изучение матчасти, а потом понять, что к созданию своей игры это тебя не приблизило.) Нескольких дней (или нескольких недель) чтения гайдов и экспериментов должно быть уже достаточно, чтобы делать несложные игрушки.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , На SDL2 платформеры делать можно будет, ведь так?

Comment: @MickeyU Да, но от библиотеки это не особо зависит. SDL2 (да и любая похожая библиотека) позволяет просто рисовать разные картинки в разных местах.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , к слову, как решить проблему " не удается открыть файл SDL2.lib"?

Comment: Вижуал студио не пользуюсь, не знаю. Задайте новый вопрос, сообщите все детали, может кто подскажет.

Comment: А что тогда использовать , если не visual studio?